# Biber problem with a bib file exported by Mendeley

Tags: biblatex, biber

I was trying `biblatex`/`biber` in TexWorks.
The LaTeX and bib file works when I use `biblatex` but failed to compile when I use biber.

Here are my LaTeX file and the bib file. The last entry in the bib file is my entry copied from my bib file. Other entries are from the working example file.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/guest/Desktop/testing_biblatex/biblatex-examples_local.bib}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}
%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{geer}.   
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\autocite{loh}.
    This is the problematic entry \citep{Albert2007}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
@Thesis{geer,
  author       = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title        = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  date         = 1985,
  subtitle     = {The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological
                  Study},
  location     = {Uppsala},
  options      = {useprefix=false},
  hyphenation  = {british},
  annotation   = {This is a typical \texttt{thesis} entry for a PhD thesis. Note
                  the \texttt{type} field in the database file which uses a
                  localization key. Also note the format of the printed name and
                  compare the \texttt{useprefix} option in the \texttt{options}
                  field as well as \texttt{vangennep}},
}

@Thesis{loh,
  author       = {Loh, Nin C.},
  title        = {High-Resolution Micromachined Interferometric Accelerometer},
  type         = {mathesis},
  institution  = {Massachusetts Institute of Technology},
  date         = 1992,
  location     = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  hyphenation  = {american},
  annotation   = {This is a typical \texttt{thesis} entry for an MA thesis. Note
                  the \texttt{type} field in the database file which uses a
                  localization key},
}

@Article{Albert2007,
author = {Albert, I and Mavrich, TN and Tomsho, LP and Qi, J and Zanton, SJ and Schuster, S.C. and Pugh, B.F.},
issn = {0028-0836},
journal = {Nature},
keywords = {nucleosome},
mendeley-tags = {nucleosome},
number = {7135},
pages = {572--576},
publisher = {Nature Publishing Group},
title = {{Translational and rotational settings of H2A. Z nucleosomes across the Saccharomyces cerevisiae genome}},
url = {http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v446/n7135/abs/nature05632.html},
volume = {446},
year = {2007}
}
```

Comment: Your `.bib` file lacks the closing `}` for `Albert2007`. Fixing that, your code works for me. `:)`

Comment: Same for me....

Comment: Does it? I'm afraid I missed the closing } while copying to here. My file has the closing }, yet it does not work. :(

Comment: I can confirm it works. Did you run Biber?

Comment: Yes. If I run it with backend=bibtex, then it works. I noticed some differences in bib fields, such as date vs year. I deleted the fields one by one and if I deleted extra fields and changed the remaining names to the same as the examples, then it works. I'm using MikTeK 2.9 and biber installed through the package management tool. Maybe the version problem?

Comment: With `backend=bibtex` or `backend=bibtex8` it works.

Comment: @Michael, yes it works with `backend=bibtex`. But I couldn't make the bibliography work with `backend=biber`. Other commenters reported that the code worked. But I couldn't without heavily editing the bib file.

Comment: I have this problem as well (works with backend=bibtex but not with biber), but since I don't have much time to spend on the code at the moment, I use it, although the other solution might be better. The PDF is fine, so I can do this in the next document.

Comment: It seems that I've got a clue. Biber is _very_ sensitive to the field name. For instance, if I change `data` to `year` in a working example, biber failed to process the bib file. Some extra fields added by Mendeley also caused the same problem. As @Michael said, I may need to stick to bibtex for a little longer.

Comment: Ahh this might explain my problems as well. The .bib file is exported from Endnote, I am not sure, how good this is.

Comment: Mendeley and biber work well together for me (I've got a few hundred references, most automatically completed) so they're mostly compatible.  What output/errors do you see when you compile?

Comment: @SamMason, Good for you. And it is strange to me because if I change the field name from `date` to `year` or add `keywords` field, biber failed. I thought `year` is a standard name for a bibtex file. What version do you use?

Comment: version of what?  Mendeley reports 1.10.1, and I've got the most recent texlive version of biber which is still 1.7.  Yes, most of entries contain a `year` field, and quite a few a `month` field as well.  Mendeley seems to have automatically put `keywords` fields in for me as well, although I don't tend to use them myself.

Comment: @microbe, What do you mean with "biber failed"? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @pst, the compilation failed. What I found is, the field name of the bib file is important. For example, the Mendeley exported bib file has 'year' instead of 'date'. The file can be complied with bibtex but not with biber. If I change 'year' to 'date', biber works.

Answer (score 0):

if you export bibtex with mendeley, you should also empty Mendeley's trash before the export. otherwise you may have duplicate bibtex entries in your bibtex file (which may cause problems).

btw. if you are looking for an alternative, or enhancement, to Mendeley, you may be interested in Docear, a software I am developing: http://www.docear.org/2013/10/17/docear-1-0-stable-a-new-video-new-manual-new-homepage-new-details-page/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In my case, however, duplicate entries were not the problem because even a single entry can cause a problem as in my example.